# How to format an SD card for Monoprice Select Mini V2?

Tags: sd, microsd, monoprice-select-mini

I bought a 32 GB SDHC (Sandisk) I'd like to use for my Monoprice 3D printer.
I have downloaded Partition Wizard and partitioned a 2GB primary partition formatted as FAT and it still does not show any files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrintnig.SE!

Answer (score 7):

For an SD card to work with the printer firmware [Monoprice suggests to format the SD card to FAT32](https://monopricesupport.kayako.com/article/59-why-is-my-printer-not-reading-my-sd-card).

However, the Monoprice Select Mini V2 is not able to read SDHC memory cards, it is advised to use an SD card (smaller than 4 GB) instead.

According to the [Monoprice support website](https://monopricesupport.kayako.com/): ["Why is my printer not reading my SD card?"](https://monopricesupport.kayako.com/article/59-why-is-my-printer-not-reading-my-sd-card):

> If the SD card is not recognized on the printer or if the files are
>   not reading, it could be an issue with the actual card itself. The
>   first thing we recommend checking is that none of the print files on
>   the SD card contain a space in their name. This shows in the printer
>   as an unidentified character and can cause issues. If none of your
>   prints contain spaces, we recommend reformatting your SD card.
>
> Note:  If you choose to purchase an SD card, ***please make sure that it
>   is not labeled HC (High Capacity)*** as it ***may not be compatible with the
>   printer***. This means that ***the card must be smaller than 4GB in size***.

The last part of the support page is probably applicable to your card.

Some further information can be found in [What is the largest microSD card that a Monoprice Select Mini can read?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/what-is-the-largest-microsd-card-that-a-monoprice-select-mini-can-read), specifically [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5311/5740). From this latter answer, I quote:

> Cards between 2 GB and 32 GB ***might*** work, depending on the specifics of
>   the card

Basically there are no guarantees when using large cards.

Comment: This is kind of scary... HC is the standard way to make and sell SD cards now, and "regular" non-HC cards are getting harder to come by.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, bad choice of the printer developer to choose for the old format. I'm just the messenger, it is an official statement release from the printer OEM.

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems formatting micro SD cards for my Monoprice Mini v2. I have some 256 MB cards tried formatting them FAT FAT32 etc, no luck.

Then I downloaded a program called [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/) did the format on the card with this and the card is now readable in the printer.